How to maintain the rxdart broadcast stream listner when using bloc with stateless widget and navigating between screens?
I am learning flutter and flutter_bloc:8.1.6. I am developing a simple app where a user can add or edit their transactions and see a list of transactions when a new transaction is added or updated.
Under the hood, my repository exposes a stream of data using rxDart Behaviour subject like below:
class TransactionRepository {
  final LocalDB _database;
  final BehaviorSubject<List<Transaction>> _transactionsController =
      BehaviorSubject.seeded([]);

  TransactionRepository({required LocalDB database}) : _database = database {
    _init();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    try {
      final transactions = await _getAllTransactions();
      _transactionsController.add(transactions);
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Stream<List<Transaction>> streamTransactions() {
    return _transactionsController.asBroadcastStream();
  }

  /// Save a transaction
  Future<void> createTransaction(NewTransaction transaction) async {
    try {
      await _database
            .into(_database.transactionTable)
            .insert(TransactionTableCompanion(
              //... fields
            ));

      final transactions = await _getAllTransactions();
      _transactionsController.add(transactions);
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}

With bloc, I am absorbing this stream like below:
  ...
class TransactionsBloc extends Bloc<TransactionsEvent, TransactionsState> {
  final TransactionRepository _transactionRepository;

  TransactionsBloc({required TransactionRepository transactionRepository})
      : _transactionRepository = transactionRepository,
        super(const TransactionsState(
            transactionStatus: TransactionsStatus.initial)) {
    on<TransactionsEvent>(
      (event, emit) => event.map(
        loadAll: (event) => _loadTransactions(event, emit),
        error: (event) => _errorLoadingTransactions(event, emit),
      ),
      transformer: null,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _loadTransactions(
      TransactionsEvent event, Emitter<TransactionsState> emit) async {
    try {
      emit(state.copyWith(transactionStatus: TransactionsStatus.fetching));

      await emit.forEach(
        _transactionRepository.streamTransactions(),
        onData: (transactions) {
          if (transactions.isEmpty) {
            return state.copyWith(
              transactionStatus: TransactionsStatus.initial,
              transactions: [],
            );
          }

          return state.copyWith(
            transactionStatus: TransactionsStatus.fetchedSuccessfully,
            transactions: transactions,
          );
        },
        onError: (e, s) {
          return state.copyWith(
            transactionStatus: TransactionsStatus.fetchingFailed,
            message: 'Error loading transaction(s)',
          );
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      add(const TransactionsEvent.error('Error loading transaction(s)'));
    }
  }
}
...


And this bloc is hooked to my main.dart StatelessWidget like:
...
return CupertinoApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: RepositoryProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) {
            final database = context.read<DatabaseCubit>();
            return TransactionRepository(
              database: database.state,
            );
          },
          child: BlocProvider(
            create: (BuildContext context) => TransactionsBloc(
              transactionRepository: context.read<TransactionRepository>(),
            )..add(const TransactionsEvent.loadAll()),  // stream is subscribed here
            child: const HomeScreen(title: appTitle),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
...

My HomeScreen StatelessWidget looks like:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        leading: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.line_horizontal_3),
        trailing: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => const AddNewTransaction(),
              ),
            );
          },
          icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
        ),
      ),
      child: const TransactionsList(),
    );
  }

TransactionList StatelessWidget where the list is finally being displayed:
BlocBuilder<TransactionsBloc, TransactionsState>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, TransactionsState state) {
          switch (state.transactionStatus) {
            case TransactionsStatus.initial:
              return TransactionListItem(
                  transaction: Transaction.nullTransaction);
            case TransactionsStatus.fetching:
              return const Center(
                child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
              );
            case TransactionsStatus.fetchedSuccessfully:
              return GroupedTransactionsListView(
                transactions:
                    state.transactions ?? [Transaction.nullTransaction],
                // transactions: state.transactions ?? [],
              );
            case TransactionsStatus.fetchingFailed:
              return Center(
                child: Text(state.message ?? 'Error loading transaction(s)'),
              );
            default:
              return const Center(
                child: Text('Something went wrong! :('),
              );
          }
        },
      ),

What is happening now is that when the app starts, the stream gets subscribed successfully and I can see all the data in my transaction list.
The user navigates to AddTransaction page (see HomeScreen -> navigation) and adds a new transaction. When they click "Save", a new entry is added to the database and upon save success, the user is navigated back (using Navigation.pop).
Now, when the user comes back to this TransactionList page, the list is not updated.
I debugged the flow and to my understanding, the stream listner (_loadTransactions) is closed.
So I want to understand and learn if and how can I maintain the stream from getting closed?
From what I have gathered so far, one way is to switch to StatefulWidget, and that's alright but I want to explore new ideas around StatelessWidget first.
If that's not possible, what is the recommended way to trigger re-subscribing the stream when a user navigated back to TransactionList page?
Thanks in advance!
Edit: Working prototype of above: https://github.com/pkimtani/oma-dhan/tree/feature/new-transaction

maybe i missed something but you store all the transactions in the db (await _database...), right? if so, why dont you read it in your TransactionList page?

That's exactly the aim.I  am learning ways to develop a reactive repository and then use event-subscription model to update the TransactionList

I've now added a link to the repo on github.

and whats LocalDB in final LocalDB _database;? cannot you "turn" it as a reactive database? like drift for example ("Stream queries: Drift lets you "watch" your queries with zero additional effort. Any query can be turned into an auto-updating stream that emits new items when the underlying data changes.")?

Well that's a good point. I am already using drift and can make the the database reactive, but my challenge is coming from observing this stream. What I am not able to achieve is when I am navigating away from the TransactionList and coming back to it, the TransactionList widget doesn't get any updates published.
I've added the link to my repo in case you want to take a better look at it or run it locally to get a better understanding of what I am trying to say here.

Also, additionally, at some point in future, I will hook it up to an API so the data source will be a hybrid of API and Database. Therefore I would need the reactivity to be at repo level where the data from all sources is getting resolved togehter.

honestly i dont understand what do you need that stream for... your "Single source of truth" should be your database, if you added some event to your stream, the new state is emitted immediately while you are in AddTransaction - it will not be repeated when you come back to TransactionList, if you want to read it here then read it from the database (i mean bloc should read it from your db) - also if your db is modified from some outside sources it will notify your BlocBuilder as the drift is "reactive" and you can listen to its changes)

I can understand your confusion, may be I am not making myself clear. I will try again.
My objective at this stage is to update my TransactionList with all the data from a stream (irrespective of where it comes from - database, API, etc..)
The part where you said "if you want to read it here then read it from the database (i mean bloc should read it from there)" is the part I am trying to figure out on how to make bloc read the repo from this stream in the background. Or if that's at all possible.

https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/dart-api/select/ you need watch() method to get a stream

Alright that did solve the issue! Many thanks!!
Can you link me to where I can learn about it, if I want to make a similar stream of my own in case there was no database involved here?
Also, can you post an answer here so I can accept it :)

inho you have to store your data somewhere - you cannot just use sink.add(...) since that new data will be at the same moment dispatched but there is no one who could listen for it (in AddTransaction) and it will be lost - thats why you need to store in your database for later use (in TransactionList), with "reactive" drift you insert your data and when you return to TransactionList you get the stream with the current snapshot and any changes that could be done later by any external iserts/updates/deletes

So, method _loadTransactions(event, emit) is triggered in bloc on TransactionsEvent. In the main.dart you do:
... add(const TransactionsEvent.loadAll()).

And your bloc handling this event. But then, when you do the transaction, in the repo you put event to the stream(not to the bloc) and this is correct. But your bloc is not listening stream in the repo all time. It trying to listen repo stream after  new TransactionsEvent only. As there are no new TransactionsEvent, method _loadTransactions not called and your UI is not updated.
What you could do here:
class TransactionsBloc extends Bloc< TransactionsEvent, TransactionsState> {
  final TransactionRepository _repository
  final StreamSubscription _subscription;

      Bloc1(TransactionRepository repository) : 
        _repository = repository,
        super(TransactionsState()) {
        ...
        _subscription = repository.streamTransactions().listen(
          onData: (transactions) {
             if (transactions.isEmpty) {
               return state.copyWith(
                   transactionStatus: TransactionsStatus.initial,
                   transactions: [],
               );
             }

             return state.copyWith(
               transactionStatus: TransactionsStatus.fetchedSuccessfully,
               transactions: transactions,
             );
          },
          onError: (e, s) {
            return state.copyWith(
              transactionStatus: TransactionsStatus.fetchingFailed,
              message: 'Error loading transaction(s)',
            );
          },
       );
      }

      @override
      Future<void> close() {
        _subscription?.cancel();
        return super.close();
      }
    }
...

You should listen stream from repo in bloc and react by emiting state on every event from stream.

Thanks for your answer and highlithing the unclear part. I've updated the Bloc implementation in my question now. Bloc provides a really nice wrapper to manage listeneing to streams with await emit.forEach(...) and I am using that in my _loadTransactions() function to subscribe to the stream.

I've now added a link to the repo on github.

I've updated answer with explanations but recipe to fix it is the same
